# Java HTTP server is not rendering images properly

Tags: java, http, websocket

I'm working on a simple HTTP web server in Java using sockets. I'm currently working on a feature that allows me to render static files automatically. Everything works fine, I'm able to render CSS and JavaScript files, but for some reason I'm unable to render any image file.

Printing the response header does return the images bytes. And when I'm looking at the network tab  when debugging, it shows the image route returns around 381 kB of data while the image itself is 151 kB, so I assume something is returning.

When I go to the image route, it says "The image (directory) cannot be displayed, because it contains errors."

**MochaResponse.java**

```
package com.gabrielgavrilov.mocha;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MochaResponse
{

    public StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();

    MochaResponse(String status, String contentType)
    {
        this.header.append("HTTP/1.0 " + status + "\r\n");
        this.header.append("Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n");
        appendEmpty();
    }

    public void addHeader(String header, String value)
    {
        this.header.append(header + ": " + value + "\r\n");
    }

    public void setCookie(String key, String value)
    {
        addHeader("Set-Cookie", key+"="+value);
    }

    public void send(String data)
    {
        this.header.append(data);
        appendEmpty();
    }

    public void render(String fileName)
    {
        render(fileName, Mocha.VIEWS_DIRECTORY);
    }

    public void render(String fileName, String directory)
    {
        try
        {
            String fileContent = Files.readString(Paths.get(directory + fileName));
            send(fileContent);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected void renderImage(String file)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream content = new FileInputStream(Mocha.STATIC_DIRECTORY + file);

            int i = 0;
            while((i = content.read()) != -1)
            {
                this.header.append(i);
            }

            System.out.println(this.header);

            appendEmpty();
            content.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void appendEmpty()
    {
        this.header.append("\r\n");
    }

}
```

**MochaClient.java**

```
package com.gabrielgavrilov.mocha;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class MochaClient {

    MochaClient(InputStream clientInput, OutputStream clientOutput)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader sr = new InputStreamReader(clientInput);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sr);
            StringBuilder clientHeader = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()).length() != 0)
            {
                clientHeader.append(line + "\r\n");
            }

            String route = getRequestedRoute(clientHeader.toString());
            String method = getRequestedMethod(clientHeader.toString());

            handleRequest(clientHeader.toString(), route, method, clientOutput, br);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void handleRequest(String header, String route, String method, OutputStream clientOutput, BufferedReader br) throws IOException
    {
        String type = checkForStaticRoute(route);

        if(type != null)
        {
            handleStaticRoute(route, type, clientOutput);
            return;
        }

        switch(method)
        {
            case "GET":
                handleGetRequest(header, route, clientOutput);
                break;
            case "POST":
                handlePostRequest(header, route, clientOutput, br);
                break;
        }
    }

    private String checkForStaticRoute(String route) throws IOException
    {
        if(route.contains("."))
        {
            String[] routeSplit = route.split("\\.");
            return routeSplit[routeSplit.length-1];
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void handleStaticRoute(String route, String type, OutputStream clientOutput) throws IOException
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case "css":
                renderStaticFile("text/css", route, clientOutput);
                break;
            case "js":
                renderStaticFile("text/javascript", route, clientOutput);
                break;
            case "png":
                renderStaticImage("image/png", route, clientOutput);
                break;
            case "jpeg":
                renderStaticImage("image/jpeg", route, clientOutput);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void renderStaticFile(String contentType, String route, OutputStream clientOutput) throws IOException
    {
        String file = route.substring(1);
        MochaResponse response = new MochaResponse("200 OK", contentType);

        response.render(file, Mocha.STATIC_DIRECTORY);

        clientOutput.write(response.header.toString().getBytes());
        clientOutput.flush();
    }

    private void renderStaticImage(String contentType, String route, OutputStream clientOutput) throws IOException
    {
        String file = route.substring(1);
        MochaResponse response = new MochaResponse("200 OK", contentType);

        response.renderImage(file);

        clientOutput.write(response.header.toString().getBytes());
        clientOutput.flush();
    }

    ...
```

If someone could help guide me to the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Rendering an image is something that a browser could do. A server only provides the data.

Comment: *this.header.append(i);* is already treating the image as a string as you're using a `StringBuilder` to accumulate it. If you must accumulate, you should use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` but you could just write is straight out after the header

Comment: You are appending an empty line (`"\r\n"`) after the body instead of between the headers and the body. That may not be your only problem, though.

Comment: It definitely isn't the only problem. You are also effectively converting the file contents to UTF-16 when you insert bytes into a StringBuilder and then converting them to who knows what by calling `getBytes()` which you should never, ever use. It uses the default platform encoding which is different on different machines, Java versions, and may very well not be what you want. There's also a tiny chance it is what you want, in which case your program will work by mistake, until you run it on a different machine or compile it with a different version, and it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you for pointing that out. I'll take g00se's suggestion and rewrite the response class to use a byte array instead of a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your `MochaResponse` class.

- you are using a `StringBuilder` to prepare your entire HTTP response.  That is fine for HTML and CSS, which are textual formats, but an image is binary data, so you can't use a `StringBuilder` to send it.  Consider using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or `BufferedOutputStream` instead.  You can use a `PrintWriter` or `OutputStreamWriter` to write textual data into it when needed.  Otherwise, use the `StringBuilder` *only* for preparing the HTTP response headers (as the name `header` implies), and then send the raw bytes of the target file separately in the HTTP response body.
- in your constructor, you are appending 2 default lines to `header`, and then you are storing a 3rd empty line.  That 3rd line effectively terminates your HTTP response headers, causing everything you append to `header` afterwards to be treated as part of the HTTP response body, including subsequent calls to `addHeader()`.  Do not put the empty line into `header` until you are finished adding HTTP headers to it.  And, do not put an empty line after the HTTP body content at all.  That is not how an HTTP message is terminated.
- in `renderImage()`, you are reading each byte from the image file and storing the text representation of the byte's numeric value into your `StringBuider`.  For example, if you read a byte `0xFF`, you store the text value `"255"` instead.  This is why your HTTP response is much larger than the image file's actual size, and why (in part) the browser thinks the image data is invalid (the other part is because of #1 above).
- while not strictly necessary (because you are closing the socket connection after sending the response), you should include a `Content-Length` HTTP header to specify the actual byte size of the HTTP response body, no matter what file format you are sending.

That being said, there is a major problem with your `MochaClient` class, too. It is expecting the HTTP response to be purely textual only, it is not handling binary data at all.  It is just reading delimited lines of text until the server closes the connection.  This is the wrong way to read in an HTTP message.

You must stop reading lines once you have reached the empty line that separates the HTTP headers from the HTTP body.  Then you need to analyze the HTTP headers to figure out:

1. what type of data the HTTP body contains (text vs binary, etc).
2. how to read it (ie, chunked vs not, compressed vs not, etc).
3. how the response is terminated (ie, via a 0-sized chunk, the `Content-Length` header, or a socket disconnect).

Only then can you actually read in the HTTP body accordingly until the end of the proper request is reached.

That being said, Java has its own built-in [`HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) and [`HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) classes, consider using them instead of implementing the HTTP protocol from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the file contents as a string but an image is a binary file. Use a byte array to read. Don't use strings to process binaries.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but shouldn't the getBytes() automatically convert the HTTP header along with the image binary to bytes already?

Anyways, I tried loading the image to a byte array and still getting the same issue. If you look at the code, the client class renders the response by converting the HTTP header to bytes. The response class is just used to build the HTTP header.

Comment: *this.header.append(i);* is already treating the image as a string as you're using a `StringBuilder` to accumulate it. If you must accumulate, you should use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` but you could just write is straight out after the header

Comment: From the documentation `String.getBytes()`: "Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array". In general Java Strings contain unicode data not bytes. It is an incorrect usage of Java Strings to use them to contain binary data and usually ends corrupting the data, because character encodings may return a different bit sequence than the original data. Also note that `InputStreamReader` does something similar and is unsuitable for binary data.